# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'item.props.selected')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

i'm trying to implement Tab Bar from react-native-elements to my app, but i get type of error undefined is not an object(evaluating 'item.props.selected'). could you help me out!

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {


AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Tabs, Tab, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Feed from '../components/home/feed';
import Profile from '../components/home/profile';


export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    selectedTab: 'profile',
  }
}

changeTab = (selectedTab) => {
  this.setState({selectedTab})
}


  render() {
    const { selectedTab } = this.state
    return (
      <Tabs>
        <Tab
          titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
          selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
          selected={selectedTab === 'feed'}
          title={selectedTab === 'feed' ? 'FEED' : null}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} name='whatshot' size={33} />}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon color={'#6296f9'} name='whatshot' size={30} />}
          onPress={() => this.changeTab('feed')}>
          <Feed />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
          selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
          selected={selectedTab === 'profile'}
          title={selectedTab === 'profile' ? 'PROFILE' : null}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} name='person' size={33} />}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon color={'#6296f9'} name='person' size={30} />}
          onPress={() => this.changeTab('profile')}>
          <Profile />
        </Tab>
        /* ... more tabs here */
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

please help me! and this is error details:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.props.selected')

```
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native-tab-navigator\TabNavigator.js:58:46
forEachSingleChild
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react\lib\ReactChildren.js:51:12
traverseAllChildrenImpl
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:77:13
traverseAllChildrenImpl
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:93:46
traverseAllChildren
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:172:33
forEachChildren
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react\lib\ReactChildren.js:71:22
_updateRenderedSceneKeys
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native-tab-navigator\TabNavigator.js:53:27
TabNavigator
C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native-tab-navigator\TabNavigator.js:31:55
```